# onResume/onPause on iOS application

Tags: ios

On Android, when I write an application, I need to implement onResume/onPause for my activity to go to background and come back from foreground. I have googled if I need how to to the same thing for iOS. But I can't find anything useful. Can you please tell me what do I need to do to handle my iOS app going to background and coming back to foreground?

Thank you.

Comment: I hope solved this, see my answer for the right thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a dedicated class that receives delegate callbacks (from the application instance itself) for these events usually called XXXApplicationDelegate.

There you need to implement delegate methods for the application lifecycle.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

Comment: The question refers to the controller lifecycle as opposed to application lifecycle.

Comment: I guess the closest to `onPause`/`onResume` is, for example, to post [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) from `applicationDidEnterBackground`/`applicationWillEnterForeground` and receive them from the controller.

Answer (score 20):

In Swift you can use

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onPause), name:
        UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onResume), name:
        UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

with

```
@objc func onPause() {
    
}

@objc func onResume() {

}
```

Note that in practice I found replacing `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` with `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` worked better because `onResume` is then also triggered if you click the Home button twice to open the iOS 'open apps' screen, then click the app immediately to focus it.

Comment: This is the correct answer, onPause and onResume are called everytime the ViewController is placed/restored from background. Thanks

Comment: where to paste this code?

Comment: works well. 
The only differences comparing how Android activity lifecycle works are: 
- it's not called after the initial initialization of ViewController (onResume). 
- also if you navigate away from this viewController to the next screen e.g (onPause).

Comment: @tomysek it can be viewDidLoad. In some initial ViewController lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 17):

You are looking for

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {}
```

for onPause

and

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {}
```

for onResume

Other answers are referring to the application lifecycle callbacks as opposed to controller (Activity in Android) callbacks.

Comment: That's simply not correct. The OP clearly asks "what do I need to do to handle my iOS app going to background and coming back to foreground?"
The two methods you quoted do NOT correspond to the app going BACK/FORG, but instead any view controller's root view lifecycle which is a totally different thing.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the Android documentation on the specific methods in question and what they do. onResume and onPause are related to the activity as opposed to the application lifecycle. Also there's a mention of activity in the question. So that's 2 against 1 if it's a matter of semantics. Why not review your answer?

Comment: To make it clear, Android's `onResume` is called every time the activity comes to the foreground, even when switching apps back and forth or turning the screen off and on. On the other side, iOS `viewDidAppear` is only called once when the controller view appeared on the screen for the first time.

Comment: viewDidAppear just run once but onResume in android run every time you enter to the activity.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want the equivalent of Android onResume/onPause for "activity to go to background and come back from foreground", which is not necessarily one-to-one with the application lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take a look at the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) on application lifecycle.  Specifically, you are interested in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Comment: The question refers to the controller lifecycle as opposed to application lifecycle

Comment: Posting the same comment more than one time doesn't make it more correct.